# Python. "relacionar" una variable de una lista con dos o mas variables de otra lista para hacer un print

Tags: python, lista

tengo un problema al querer mostrar los "instrumentos musicales" a comprar en mi código.
según el código avanza va guardando los datos que uno entrega en las listas vacías del principio, la cosa es que al momento de ingresar un par de clientes con mas de un instrumento y elegir la opción 2 para ver los datos me muestra solamente un elemento la lista.

me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de arreglarlo para que muestre todos los instrumentos que ingresé con un cliente en especifico

```
ruts = []
nombres = []
correos = []
Instrumentos = []

respuesta = ""
while respuesta != "3":

    print("1) Registrar Cliente")
    print("2) Datos Cliente")
    print("3) Salir")
    respuesta = input("¿Qué desea hacer? ")

    if respuesta == "1":
        rut = 1
        while rut < 5_000_000 or rut > 99_999_999:
            try:
                rut = int(input("Ingrese rut sin guión ni puntos: "))
            except:
                print("Rut incorrecto.")
                rut = 1
        ruts.append(rut)

        correo = ""
        correo = str(input("Ingrese correo: "))
        while not "@" in correo:
            print("Ingrese un correo válido.")
            correo = str(input("Ingrese correo: "))
        correos.append(correo)

        nombre = ""
        while nombre == "":
                nombre = str(input("Ingrese nombre: "))
        nombres.append(nombre)

        instrumento = "si"
        while instrumento == "si":
            try:
                instrumento = str(input("Ingrese Instrumento musical para comprar: "))
                Instrumentos.append(instrumento)
                instrumento = input("¿Desea agregar otro? ")
            except:
                ("Ingrese una respuesta entre si o no")

    elif respuesta == "2": 
        try:
            rutbuscado = int(input("Ingrese rut a consultar: "))
            indice = ruts.index(rutbuscado)
            print("\nDatos de", nombres[indice])
            print("--"*20)
            print("Nombre:",nombres[indice])
            print("Rut:",ruts[indice])
            print("Correo:",correos[indice])
            print("Instrumentos musicales:",Instrumentos[indice])
            print("--"*20)
        except:
            print("Rut incorrecto.")
    elif respuesta == "3":
        print("Ha salido del sistema...")
        pass
    else:
        print("escoja una opcion correcta por favor... \n")
```

Comment: tienes que usar listas necesariamente???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es simple: tienes una lista de instrumentos, pero lo que necesitas es una **lista de listas** de instrumentos.

Actualmente `Instrumentos` contiene una lista de **todos** los instrumentos ingresados, sin importar cliente.

```
Instrumentos => ["guitarra", "flauta", "trombón"]
```

Entonces, `Instrumentos[0]` es simplemente el primer instrumento en la lista: "guitarra"

**Solución**

Cuando se ingresa un cliente, guardar en una lista nueva sus instrumentos. Al terminar de ingresarlos, agregar la lista a `Instrumentos`. Suponiendo dos clientes, el primero con dos instrumentos, la lista quedaría así:

```
Instrumentos => [["guitarra", "flauta"],
                 ["trombón"]]
```

Con esto todas las listas quedan pareadas: los datos de un clientes usan el mismo indice en las varias listas.

```
instrumento = "si"
seleccion = []
while instrumento == "si":
    try:
        instrumento = str(input("Ingrese Instrumento musical para comprar: "))
        seleccion.append(instrumento)
        instrumento = input("¿Desea agregar otro? ")
    except:
        ("Ingrese una respuesta entre si o no")
Instrumentos.append(seleccion)
```

Comment: muchas gracias!